# No server response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri, strong-parameters

I really can't find the solution for this. I'm trying to access a game API to fill platform (PS3 Xbox) information for the games I insert manually. All information about the game that I have (like the name of the game) is in strong params. So I use the name that I inserted manually to get platform using the API.

When I try the first example, things works just well, but the second example, I got no answer from the server. Nothing happens when I submit to the create action, not a single line on server logs :-/

The only difference between the examples is the way I save game's name to make the API request. I'm using Nokogiri Gem to parse API's XML and the code looks fine to me.

Can you help me?

Thanks,

**Example 1 (works well):**

```
def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    firstUrl = "http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=sonic"

    # I'm hardcoding a game just for debug 

    gameList = Nokogiri::XML(open(firstUrl))

    gameApiId = gameList.css("Game id").first.text

    secondUrl = "http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=" + gameApiId

    gameInformation = Nokogiri::XML(open(secondUrl))

    @game.platform = gameInformation.xpath("//Game//Platform").text

       if @game.save
        redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.'
       else
        render :new
       end
end

    private

      def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:name, :publisher, :year, :description, :image, levels_attributes: [:id, :name, :sort_order, :_destroy])
      end
```

**Example 2 (no response from server)**

```
def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    firstUrl = "http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=" + @game.name.gsub(/\s+/, "")

    # I'm hardcoding a game just for debug 

    gameList = Nokogiri::XML(open(firstUrl))

    gameApiId = gameList.css("Game id").first.text

    secondUrl = "http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=" + gameApiId

    gameInformation = Nokogiri::XML(open(secondUrl))

    @game.platform = gameInformation.xpath("//Game//Platform").text

       if @game.save
        redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.'
       else
        render :new
       end
end

    private

      def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:name, :publisher, :year, :description, :image, levels_attributes: [:id, :name, :sort_order, :_destroy])
      end
```

Comment: Print the URL before requesting then test the URL in the browser

Answer (score 0):

In summary, the difference is this:

```
firstUrl = "http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=" + @game.name.gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

What you're going to get on here are tips on how to `debug` this issue. The problem is since you're pinging a third-party API, we have scant information on what the returned data is *meant* to be like, making any "solution" a case of stabbing in the dark

--

**Debug**

I would do several things:

> 1. Make sure this new link is accessible & returns data
> 2. Make sure the rest of the variables & data is intact
> 3. Ensure the third party API is able to provide the return you want

I suspect the issue will be with the way you're calling `@game.name.gsub` - **have you confirmed this is indeed being called**?

I just tested the url `http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=StarFox` and it brought back data. Upon initial insepction, I would suspect the crux of the issue is with your calling of this `url`

Comment: Making it simple, this code does not work. I reduced the code to this and the same problem occurs. Do you have any ideia? Seems that my problem is with "puts @ game".  

    def create

    @ game = Game.new(game_params)

     puts @ game

     if @game.save
    redirect_to @ game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.'
    else
    render :new
    end
    end

    private

    def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:name, :publisher, :year,     :description, :image, levels_attributes: [:id, :name, :sort_order, :_destroy])
    end

*space after @ is stackOv.comment police.